# Sqlite translation to Flask-SQAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to databases. I have a SQLite database that needs to be refactored into SQLAlchemy, to be owned by Postgres.

This often happens when you have a file system database that needs to move into production, and live in a cluster environment like Docker Swarm, where data needs to be shared between containers. SQLite is not made for that, I suppose.

I have searched for ways of translating from SQLite syntax to SQAlchemy, but all I find is about migrations. I don't need that. I need to refactor the code, and understand the differences of syntax regarding:

1. creation of tables
2. the insertion of data
3. relationships between tables.

### SQLite

This is my code for creating SQLite tables, and their indexes, as well as onde example which performs operations with tables and create relationships between them.

```
class crawler:
    # Initialize the crawler with the name of database
    def __init__(self, dbname):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect(
            dbname, 
            timeout=10)

    def __del__(self):
        self.con.close()

    def dbcommit(self):
        self.con.commit()

# Create the database tables
def create_index_tables(self):

    self.con.execute('create table urllist(url)')
    self.con.execute('create table wordlist(word)')
    self.con.execute('create table wordlocation(urlid,wordid,location)')
    self.con.execute('create table link(fromid integer,toid integer)')
    self.con.execute('create table linkwords(wordid,linkid)')
    self.con.execute('create index wordidx on wordlist(word)')
    self.con.execute('create index urlidx on urllist(url)')
    self.con.execute('create index wordurlidx on wordlocation(wordid)')
    self.con.execute('create index urltoidx on link(toid)') 
    self.con.execute('create index urlfromidx on link(fromid)') 
    self.dbcommit()


def calculate_pagerank(self,iterations=20):

    # clear out the current PageRank tables
    self.con.execute('drop table if exists pagerank')
    self.con.execute('create table pagerank(urlid primary key,score)')
    # initialize every url with a PageRank of 1
    self.con.execute('insert into pagerank select rowid, 1.0 from urllist') 
    self.dbcommit( )

    for i in range(iterations):
        print ("Iteration %d" % (i))
        for (urlid,) in self.con.execute('select rowid from urllist'):
            pr=0.15
            # Loop through all the pages that link to this one
            for (linker,) in self.con.execute(
            'select distinct fromid from link where toid=%d' % urlid):
                # Get the PageRank of the linker
                linkingpr=self.con.execute(
                'select score from pagerank where urlid=%d' % linker).fetchone()[0]         
                # Get the total number of links from the linker 
                linkingcount=self.con.execute(
                'select count(*) from link where fromid=%d' % linker).fetchone()[0] 
                pr+=0.85*(linkingpr/linkingcount)
            self.con.execute(
        'update pagerank set score=%f where urlid=%d' % (pr,urlid)) 
        self.dbcommit( )
```

then I would:

```
crawler=crawler('searchindex.db')

crawler.create_index_tables() #DONE once

crawler.calculate_pagerank()

cur = crawler.con.execute('select * from pagerank order by score desc')

print ([row for row in crawler.con.execute(
    'select rowid from wordlocation where wordid=10')])
```

and so on.

---

### SQALChemy

And this is how I build my SQAlchemy models (unrelated to my SQLite tables above), with an example of a relationship. This model is already being owned by Postgres.

```
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __bind_key__ = 'db1'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)

    menu = db.relationship("Menu",
                    backref=db.backref('user'), 
                    uselist=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
     return '<ID %r>, <Coffeeshop %r>, <Username %r>' % (self.id,
                                                         self.username)

    def serialize(self):
       return { 
        'id': self.id,
        'username': self.username,
        'email': self.email,
        'menu' : [ item.serialize() for item in self.menu],
        }
```

with this model you can simply add:

```
db.session.add(User(
            username=username, 
            email=email, 
            password=password))
db.session.commit()
```

query:

```
users = User.query.all()
```

serialize:

```
[user.serialize() for user in User.query.all()]
```

---

My goal is to refactor my former SQLite db using this latter SQAlchemy type of model for tables.

What confuses me the most here is the need to declare indexes for tables in SQLite, and how that need translates to SQAlchemy.

Can anyone point me in the right direction starting with my SQLite code above?

Comment: Meta-note: if you can, please try to remember that names of software (eg. SQLite, PostgreSQL) are not code, and should be formatted just using the correct case rules for proper nouns (or stylised proper nouns).

Comment: @halfer, So the question should not use the term 'translate' but rather "reformat"?

Comment: No, I am not referring to the language of this post. I am referring to the formatting (`like so`). See also my [edit note](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60287274/revisions).